# Broken link to our advice on writing great tag wikis

Tags: bug, tag-wiki, blog, broken-link

When editing a tag wiki on any site (for example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/1)), the following link is shown:

> See our advice on [writing great tag wikis](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/).

It leads to https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/
However, this page cannot be found.

Comment: Page exists now, probably some temporary glitch in blog.

Comment: @ShadowWizard We use a Jekyll-based blog generation system. Unfortunately, sometimes some of the pages do not generate correctly, thus causing the files to be missing. Regenerating the blog usually solves this, but knowing when we have a "busted blog build" is half the battle. (The other half of the battle is fixing the system for good so that all pages generate correctly all the time.)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young thanks, I know it's a long battle, and it sounds like an epic battle indeed. Good luck, and may the best dev win! :D

Comment: @Chris on a more serious note, there are lots of reports, old and new, about those missing pages in blog, none is "generic" though, i.e. each reporting a single missing page spotted by someone. Think it's good idea to start a "generic" bug report with details about the actual bug, that you'll mark [tag:status-completed] when the battle will be won?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sure, probably a good idea.

Comment: @Chris [done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267556/blog-sometimes-losing-pages-due-to-picking-up-incorrect-configuration). Can you please make it Community Wiki? I don't feel like I should get reputation for reporting something that is already reported many times.